# Android listView with CheckedTextView, populate with few checked rows

Tags: android, listview, checked, checkedtextview

I am new to android,I am trying to show a listview with CheckedTextView on screen with few elements already checked, But couldn't succeed, my listview is always unchecked
Here is my code,

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BusRoutesList);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.routes_list_item, R.id.stop_checkedtextbox, routesSubList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
for (int i = 0; i < routesSubList.size(); i++) {
            if (selectedRoutesList.contains(routesSubList.get(i))) {
                //listView.setItemChecked(i,true); No Luck
                View v = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
                CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.stop_checkedtextbox);

                checkedTextView.setChecked(true);//I get correct row to be checked but not shown on screen

            }
        }
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stop_checkedtextbox);
                boolean checked = checkedTextView.isChecked();
                // String str =
                if (checked) {
                    checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
                    selectedRoutesList.remove(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                } else {
                    selectedRoutesList.add(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                    checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Please advice, I dont know if i am missing something

Comment: Don't check views in ListView - it is futile - they're recycled, to correctly set item to be checked in ListView use [ListView.setItemChecked](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html) method

Comment: tried with setItemChecked also No Luck                                               for (int i = 0; i < routesSubList.size(); i++) {
            if (selectedRoutesList.contains(routesSubList.get(i))) {
                listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
                /*View v = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
                CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.stop_checkedtextbox);

                checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
                */
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given the listView a custom layout, so it don't know how it should be looked when an item is checked. You can try with override the getView().

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.routes_list_item, R.id.stop_checkedtextbox, routesSubList){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.routes_list_item);
            }
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stop_checkedtextbox);
            if(listView.isItemChecked(position)){
                checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    };
```

The code is not tested. Hope it help!

Comment: Thank you it worked, But i am stuck with new issue my list was invisible when i Toast for OnClicks i get correct response

Comment: I saw the code you post in the next answer. Try replaced inflater with, getActivity().getLayoutInflater(). I think that the code you shown is in onCreateView() of Fragment. Therefore you have inflater when the view is created. But when the list item is clicked, you don't have inflater to inflat the view.

Comment: Bingo!! In the getView() i also need to set text so that it doest appear blank this piece of code solved checkedTextView.setText(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BusRoutesList);
 listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.routes_list_item,R.id.stop_checkedtextbox, routesSubList);
 listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 View v = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
 CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.stop_checkedtextbox);
   for (int i = 0; i < routesSubList.size(); i++) {
        if (selectedRoutesList.contains(routesSubList.get(i))){
            checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
         }
        else {
            checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
             }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override getView() and update CheckedTextview, while Pre-populating listview set

```
listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routes_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        if (convertView != null) {
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stop_checkedtextbox);
            if (listView.isItemChecked(position)) {
                checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
            }
```